# Cocoapods "pod update" installs old pods

Tags: ios, xcode, server, continuous-integration, cocoapods

I am trying to set up CI on Xcode Server by creating a bot for an iOS app. I use CocoaPods so I'm using the script below to install the pods:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
#!/bin/bash
cd "$XCS_SOURCE_DIR/{PROJECTNAME}"
if [ -e "Pods" ]
then
/usr/local/bin/pod update
else
/usr/local/bin/pod install
fi
```

The current version of CocoaPods 0.39.0 is installed on the server. When I run "pod update" on the server everything is alright and the newest pods are installed.

```
Using FBAudienceNetwork (4.7.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.8.0)
Using Fabric (1.6.1)
Using FyberSDK (8.1.2)
Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.6.0)
Using GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
```

When I use the script above however something strange happens.

```
Installing FBAudienceNetwork (4.1.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.4.0)
Installing Fabric (1.2.8)
Installing FyberSDK (7.2.4)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.3.1)
Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.13.0)
```

Anyone has any idea why old versions are installed with the script? I use OS X Server 5.0.15 and Xcode 7.2.

The podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target "{PROJECTNAME}" do
    inhibit_all_warnings!

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Branch'
    pod 'SwrveSDK'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'MZTimerLabel'
    pod 'pop' 
    pod 'Adjust'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FyberSDK'
    pod 'AdColony'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'ChartboostSDK'
    pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
    pod 'VungleSDK-iOS'
end

target "{PROJECTNAME}Tests" do
    inhibit_all_warnings!

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Branch'
    pod 'SwrveSDK'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'MZTimerLabel'
    pod 'pop'
    pod 'Adjust'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FyberSDK'
    pod 'AdColony'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'ChartboostSDK'
    pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Show us your Podfile

Comment: Ok, I've included the podfile in my question

Comment: Should be because the iOS version, try remove (platform :ios, "8.0")

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work. I removed the line but still the same problem

Comment: Just a last guess, try remove (config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'), Maybe some pods already have supporter to 'ENABLE_BITCODE'

Comment: no.. also doesn't work :(

Comment: I am without my mac these days, when I get back if you have not received any answer yet I try to help you more

Answer (score 35):

I've got it working now! I didn't know about the _xcsbuildd user which does the builds. I found more about this here: https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-08-17-17-30-xcode_server_tutorials_3_prebuild__postbuild_scripts/

So after logging in as this user I saw the same problem in the terminal on the server. Old versions of the pods were downloaded. The master repository of CocoaPods has some error, so I did

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

Then I ran

```
pod setup --verbose
```

And the master repository with the Cocoapods specs was installed again. Now it works!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me today. As a note for others it took ages before the cloning actually started, so first I thought it was not working. But I left it alone and it started and all was good.

Answer (score 8):

For those of you encountering this issue with newer libraries like:

- Facebook login
- 'FBSDKLoginKit'
- 'FBSDKShareKit'
- 'FBSDKCoreKit'

you need to update your cocoapods to the latest version ( currently 1.2)

I did the following which worked:
(Warning Cocoapods seems to sit idling for ages but I guess its doing something. )
Follow the first two steps from @youritrg above in terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup --verbose
```

You should now have an refreshed installation. 
I then updated by doing:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

After installation the Facebook Cocoapods installed perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me. After updating to Xcode 9, I was having the problem with Firebase

Comment: yep same for me.

Answer (score 5):

Running `pod repo update` fixed this error for me

Answer (score 4):

For me uninstalling everything then removing the master repo worked

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader 
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-stats
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try
```

then

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then

```
pod setup --verbose
```

Comment: "pod setup --verbose"  - Should we execute this command in project path or normal system path ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for digging up an old thread, but I had a similar problem with Firebase/Admob not updating.  I got the same error as others have mentioned above.  I tried everything mentioned above, but for me, the only way I could get the pods to update correctly was to comment out the line

```
use_frameworks!
```

I know that this should be included as I am using Swift, but it seems to work fine now.  If anyone has any thoughts on why, I would love to know what is going on!